# Non-unique determining parameter

Tags: interface, idris

The meaning of a determining parameter in an interface, as I understand it, is that the compiler can use that parameter to uniquely determine which implementation to use. However, I can create multiple implementations for a given determining parameter, which means the implementation's no longer unique. What does a determining parameter mean there?

For example in

```
interface Foo (a : Type) (b : Type) | b where

Foo Int String where
Foo Double String where
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you put that into Idris?  What about that outcome is perplexing or indeterminate?

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit for the official Idris Discord https://discord.gg/UX68fDs2jc than Stack Overflow. This is where the Idris developers are.

Comment: @michaelmesser it is where they are, but these questions will come up again and discord's a terrible place for reference

Comment: @joel Discord is searchable, but not index by Google. For better or worse, very few people in the Idris community use Stack Overflow, so Discord is your best bet.

Comment: @michaelmesser i'd rather put it here thanks

Comment: @joel It may make sense to ask on Discord and then post the question and answer here to others can find it

Comment: @AndreasZUERCHER in my much more complicated working case, no errors occur, but the actual behaviour isn't documented. I want to know if there are silent consequences I'm unaware of. The very nature of determining parameters suggests to me that it doesn't make sense to have multiple corresponding implementations, so I assume there's something amiss

Comment: @joel, why isn't the answer to ‘what happens’ (quite trivially) the correct behavior that you observed is what happens. Prove us wrong by overt example, counter-example, anything that is a gotcha contradiction in any language reference; state that this & that are in contradiction or are perplexing—something—anything.  Right now, the answer to ‘what happens’ is merely: the correct behavior happens, period, end of story, just as you yourself observed. Why are we chasing a ghost?  The ball is in your court to actually create a not-open-ended question. You have not asked a well-formed SO question.